# Visualforce page inputText autofilling when user clicks on dataTable cell

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a Visualforce page displaying a list of data from a custom sObject and a inputText field on the page.

onClick of the dataTable cell, I would like for the inputText field to autofill with the cell value without doing a page refresh if possible.

I am not very familiar with jQuery but gave an attempt at it which was unsuccessful.
Would there be a easier way to get a cell value in the dataTable?

```
<apex:page StandardController="License_Request__c" extensions="Controller_OlympusLR_addSingleVoucher" recordSetVar="License_Request__c" showheader="false">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js">
    $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    function clickElem(elem){
        alert($j(elem).find(".name").html());
        var dataCellValue = $j(elem).find(".name").html();
    }
    </script>
</head>    
<apex:form>
<apex:pageBlock>
<apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="overflow:auto;width;500px;height:300px" id="availableLRTable">
<apex:dataTable align="left" value="{!availableLR}" var="a" columnswidth="100px,100px" cellpadding="4" border="1" rendered="{!isRendered}" onRowClick="clickElem(this);">
    <apex:column headervalue="License Request Name" value="{!a.name}" styleClass="name" />
    <apex:column headervalue="License Voucher #" value="{!a.License_Voucher__c}" />
</apex:dataTable>
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" title="Article Information" >
    <apex:inputText label="Voucher Number: " html-placeholder="<script>dataCellvalue</script>"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Add Voucher to Project"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

**Note:** Change the code to point back to your object, I have changed your object with Account just to test the page.

```
<apex:page StandardController="account" extensions="accountext_controller" recordSetVar="account">
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" />
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="overflow:auto;width;500px;height:300px" id="availableLRTable">
<apex:dataTable align="left" value="{!Account}" var="a" columnswidth="100px,100px" cellpadding="4" border="1"  onRowClick="clickElem(this);">
    <apex:column headervalue="License Request Name">
    <apex:outputLink onclick="populatevouchernum('{!a.id}'); return false;" >{!a.id}
    </apex:outputLink>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headervalue="License Voucher #" value="{!a.name}" />
</apex:dataTable>
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" title="Article Information" >
    <apex:inputText id="input_to_change" label="Voucher Number: " value="{!data_table_value}"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Add Voucher to Project"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
<script>
function populatevouchernum(elm){
if(elm != ''){
$('[id$=input_to_change]').val(elm);
}
}
</script>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Comment: @enph happy that the solution worked for you